# Windows 10: Is it safe to move SD card from a "standby Linux" to Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows-10, file-management, standby, safely-remove-hardware

Since a month, I regularly switch an SD card between a computer with Windows 10 and a laptop with Linux Mint / Windows 10. I do not digitally "remove the card", I just take it out. The files that use the card can even stay open, and when I put back the card, I can still save them.

I assume that there is no risk if I put back the card *before* the wake-up, since the sleeping computer does not notice this and does not wake up from it. But I even got used to removing the card in standby mode and waking-up the computer if the card is not inserted.

During frequent switching from Linux to Windows 10 in the last week, I got the warning twice that I should scan and repair my SD card. Clicking on OK, I get:

[image]

and a success message:

[image]

It seems to be a Windows 10 issue, Linux does not show anything about a needed repair.

My last "LOST.DIR" folder on that card is half a year old, meaning that this switching practice does not seem to harm the data. Not sure if that folder arises from such switching at all.

[image]

**The question**

**Is this repair message just a formal act of Windows 10, or can some data be lost when moving a card from a "standby Linux" to Windows 10?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On removable devices Windows will prioritise keeping the filesystem consistent and completely written, but you should still allow *some* time after writing data before simply pulling the card out.  If it were a memory stick with an activity light then probably 30 seconds after it stopped flashing would be about right.

It is entirely possible that all you are seeing is that the filesystem has been marked ["dirty"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-dirty) before being written to and took a short while after those writes were finished to be marked "clean" again. In that case there may be no *real* data lost, just that the filesystem needed to be checked. Only you would know if there is any actual lost data.

The same might be said for Linux, but it would depend how it is set up. Linux would likely not understand or care how Windows marks the disk as "dirty".

Essentially though, yes. You *can* damage the data you are writing by ejecting too soon, or if something important has not been written yet such as the filesystem table.

You *should* be fine, especially if you've given it some time since actively writing to the card, but clicking "eject" in your operating system gives you peace of mind that it has been cleanly unmounted and all data written.

Comment: I can confirm that throwing it out digitally and waiting a bit - even if you are so used to it or lazy about it - is better than just taking it out. I have tested this again, taking it out directly led to the same repair warning.

Comment: From the page I linked in my answer you can use `fsutil dirty query c:` in an administrator command prompt (replace c: with the drive letter of your SD card) to see if it it marked dirty. I would expect that some seconds after a write it would change back to "clean" and removal will not give the error. I need to test this out properly though.

Comment: Though I'm not sure that command is telling the whole story, no matter what I do it always reports "NOT dirty" when writing to *any* disk. Tried FAT32, exFAT, NTFS, SD card, USB stick, internal HDD and SDD. It may be that it is marked by a different method or I am misreading when or how it is set.